# Make threads wait for the execution of another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, zk

In a Java ZK application, in ViewModel, I have multiple threads executing a particular function. The first time that function is executed by any thread it takes a long time but after it has been executed once, it returns immediately when executed by the other threads, as it has values retrieved in cache by then. But it should be executed by just one thread the first time, as if multiple threads execute that function, it will not return to any of them as cache remains empty when each of them calls the same functions and as a result, returning time adds up for all of them.
So how can I make other threads wait for the first thread to complete as the threads belong to different objects and thus synchronizing the method will not work here. Can a variable be used here which can communicate to the other threads that the first thread has completed? Please note that all the threads belong to different objects of the same class i.e a ViewModel and it cannot extend the thread class or implement Runnable as it is a ZK framework class.
Any solution can be suggested.

Comment: Synchronize the cache value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
static Object lock;

...

if (objectYouAreHopingHasBeenCached == null) {
  synchronized (lock) {
    if (objectYouAreHopingHasBeenCached == null) {
       // fetch the object, put in in objectYouAreHopingHasBeenCached
    }
  }
}
return objectYouAreHopingHasBeenCached;
```

Comment: This will work most of the time, but not always. A second thread may compare `objectYouAreHopingHasBeenCached` to null right after the first thread did, but right before the first thread aquired the lock.

Comment: This is why I check for the object again in the synchronized block. That way, you can have the best of both worlds - ensure it is fetched just once, but shortcut the synchronized block if its already there

Comment: double checked locking has been fixed in Java 5 + to always work *as long as the field is* **volatile** In this case  in the class declaration: `private volatile Object objectYouAreHopingHasBeenCached;`